# Texturing problem inside Unity

Tags: unity, graphics

So I created a Hex Sphere using Houdini and exported it as FBX to Maya where I created UV's for the model to use it in Unity

This is how my sphere looks inside Unity

[image]

All the hexes are separated so they act like individual gameobjects in Unity. Now I created the below texture in form of a Hex in Photoshop which looks like below
[image]

When I tried to map it inside Unity with an x-tiling of 10 and y-tiling of 12, it doesn't look right

[image]

The texturing is completely out of place. What am I doing wrong? Can this be fixed within Unity itself or do I have to go back to Maya and fix the UV's there? This could be a simple issue that could be fixed I suppose but I am not an Artist and I don't exactly know what the problem is so please help me out :)

Comment: This looks like a problem with your approach to UVs - I assume that your UV layout is made for the entire model and that your "texture" is a single tile with white background. As you are tiling, you are probably trying to repeat the same texture across the entire UV map, however the UV coordinates for each Hex seem to be non-identical, so you get strange effects. The easiest solution however would be to simply align the texture with the UVs in Maya and then import to Unity.

Comment: I thought the same but I am have never used Maya. This model was given to me by an Artist. So basically each Hex needs to have its own UV created in Maya if I am not wrong? I told him about the problem but then do we have to manually create UVs for each Hex in Maya? That would be too much of manual work. Is there a better way to do it in Maya?

Comment: This is kinda hard to answer, as I do not know how your UV Layout looks right now. You probably have a few options: 1. redo the UVs - if you want only one Hex Tile to repeat all over the model just overlap all of the Tile UVs in the center of the UV Texture Editor (your Artist will probably understand what I mean), 2. Create a Texture appropriate to your UVs (Most likely in Photoshop), this will give you a new Texture file, which will be applied to your model, 3. Programmatically change the UVs of your model (can be done in Unity as well) - probably overkill